# IntelliJ IDEA issue: xarray & pyparsing exception on import

Tags: intellij-idea, python-3.6, pyparsing, python-xarray

**This has something to do with the IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1 IDE. I do not get the following issue when executing my code via the command line.**

===========================================================================

```
Python version: 3.6.1
xarray version: 0.9.6
pandas version: 0.20.3
numpy version: 1.12.1
```

I, for the first time, would like to use `xarray`.

I imported the module (no problem here) and then, without even using the module, ran my code. For example:

```
import xarray as xr

def something():
    print("doing something...")

something()
```

This immediately throws an exception when I run it:

> Exception ignored in:  at 0x05A287B0>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 160, in
>   
>       _generatorType = type((y for y in range(1))) SystemError: error return without exception set

If I delete the `import xarray as xr` and rerun the code, I get no exception.
From the exception message, it looks like something called `pyparsing.py`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

pyparsing is probably installed as a dependency from some other package. I have run the pyparsing unit tests on both Python 3.6.1 and 3.6.2 (as well as most other popular Python versions back to 2.6) without any error.

I suspect that something in your environment is defining `range` to be something other than the normal builtin `range` method, and this is then causing the pyparsing code to fail.

I will fix this in pyparsing, to replace `range(1)` with just an empty list, which should give the same results for pyparsing, but without the susceptibility to being overwritten by a monkeypatch to `range`.

In the meantime, try explicitly importing pyparsing before importing xarray, or anything else for that matter. A simple `import pyparsing` should do.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go in the morning and let you know.